# Make chosen version of Elasticsearch run as a service in Linux

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, service, systemctl

I have an issue with later versions of ES, so have to use 7.10.2 currently.

This means that the previous method I used to install ES as a service, i.e. `apt-get`, doesn't work You can't choose an older version this way: it currently installs 7.16.3.

So I followed the procedure on [this page for 7.10](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/targz.html): everything worked: I was able to run ES as an app and also as a "daemon". Clearly I could simply put the "daemon" startup line in a script which runs on boot.

But what's the optimum way of turning this "daemon arrangement" into a service which you can control with `systemctl`, and which starts automatically when the machine boots?

PS I don't want to get involved with Docker. I'm sure that's a useful thing but I'm convinced there is a simpler way of doing it, using available Linux sys tools.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround... this doesn't in fact create a service of the "systemd" type which can be controlled by `systemctl`. There seem to be one or two problems which make this non-trivial.

1) You can't start ES as root! I assume (not sure) that most services are being run by root. Anyway this was something I couldn't find a solution to.

2) I am not sure whether a shell script file called by a service is allowed to end... or should continue endlessly: initially I thought this would be sufficient. This is a shell script (run_es_daemon.sh) which does indeed start up ES (as a daemon process) when run by manually in a terminal. There is no issue to do with the fact that the script ends and you then close the terminal: the daemon process continues to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
# start ES as a daemon...
cd /home/mike/Elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.10.2
./bin/elasticsearch -d -p pid
```

... but it never worked using a xxx.service file in /etc/systemd/system/ (maybe because of 1) above). So I also tried adding these lines under the above ones:

```
while true
do 
  echo "bubbles" 
  sleep 60
done
```

... didn't work either.

In the end I found a simple workaround solution was to start up the daemon process by using `crontab`:

```
@reboot /home/mike/sysadmin/run_es_daemon.sh
```

... but I'd still like to know how to set it up as a true service, which starts at boot...